# Xcode 6.3.1 quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6.3.1

I'm getting an error **Xcode 6.3.1 quit unexpectedly** whenever Xcode is opened. This was working fine till last night. I have tried *restart system* but didn't worked. *Reinstalling won't be feasible* approach since I have downloaded simulator and documentations (approx 8GB of data).

[image: Xcode error]

Below is details of error :

```
Process:               Xcode [816]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 6.3.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [816]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-29 12:05:22.140 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        ...


Time Awake Since Boot: 4600 seconds

Crashed Thread:        6  Dispatch queue: gputools.DYKeyedUnarchiver.0x112ce03e0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fffc6fbc3af
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any 3rd party plugins that you had installed with xcode and it should work fine.

This is probably because of DYKeyedUnarchiver.h. So remove it, restart system and  try reopening xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's working fine. **Simply kept system shut-down** for sometime. Maybe shutdown have reset all settings of Mac.

Comment: Didn't you try to restart your computer before posting this question ?

Comment: @swapnilagarwal : I have mentioned this thing in question itself.